# Laravel Markdown - Emails sent to gmail address being marked as spam

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail, markdown

This is my email template

```
@component('mail::message')
<img src="{{ URL::asset("https://mywebsite.com/openUpdate/$userId") }}" width="1" height="1" alt="">
# Hello {{$userName}},

----Email Body-----

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://mywebsite.com/redirecting/' . $userId])
Click here to confirm your appointment
@endcomponent

{{ config('app.name') }}<br>
Click <a href="{{ URL::asset("https://mywebsite.com/unsubscribe/$userId") }}">here</a> to un-subscribe.

@endcomponent
```

Whenever I send this email to a Gmail address I get the following error stating that my email is marked as possible spam

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

myemail@gmail.com
host 5817.smtp.antispamcloud.com [38.89.254.164]
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
550 High probability of spam
Reporting-MTA: dns; nwpro2.fcomet.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;myemail@gmail.com
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; 5817.smtp.antispamcloud.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 High probability of spam
```

It fails even if I strip down my email to only `@component('mail::message')` at the beginning and `@endcomponent` at the end.

It is however accepting just plain text.

How can I ensure email is properly delivered and not marked as spam?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/yoKzsIukQSc

Comment: Run your emails through a spam scoring engine, check blacklists on sites like https://mxtoolbox.com. Make sure the correct headers are present and make sure the hosting company servers aren't black listed. But my advice would be to use an email service like https://www.mailgun.com/, it's more convenient and easy to implement.

Comment: @O.S.Kaya You are right. The exactly same Email Template is getting delivered right to the inbox when I use mailgun.com.
So it is the fault of my hosting company?

Comment: Please note you can delete this question to get back rep lost to downvotes. The question is not one that can be answered here because it's nothing to do with your code, only external servers that you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

Using server php mail() function always bad idea, because your hosting provider is hosting service, not mail transfer service. It's different services. If you want to get mails into inbox you may order vps with dedicated IP address and start managing domain/ip reputation, or you can order services from sendgrid, mailgun or etc. 
Also be ready to implement standard email policy like 2 opt in, and even better - you can check mails before sending with some service like [mailcheck.co](https://mailcheck.co)
You need really low bounce rate on your mails to keep good reputation of your ip/domain. If you use some 3rd party mail sending service they will manage ip reputation for you, but also they will measure yours bound rate and spam rate. If your rates will be above average they will ban yours account.
Sending email nowdays isn't easy task due to numerous technologies related to antispam, like DKIM, SPF, DMARC etc.
In conclusion - I still got spam in my inbox, but I can't send email from my server anymore without extra efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but I stopped using markdown and using view() for now.

Of course, we need to have a plain HTML template for view blade files.

**(UPDATED=>)**

The actual problem was: There was one link on the button and it was different from the sender domain.
We should include links that can have the sender domain used.